# "activator.createinstance()" gives error when try to run

Tags: c#, reflection

I was unable to solve the following error. I'll appreciate your help.

I have the following class:

```
public class GB
{
        private StreamReader sr;
        public GB()
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:\\temp.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
        }
        public int MultiCall()
        {
            if (sr.ReadLine() == "test1")
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

in my form, there is button with the following function;

```
void buttonClick()
{
  myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllpath); // dllpath is the dll file for GB class
  myType = myAssembly .GetType("GB");
  myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

  myMethodInfo = myType .GetMethod("MultiCall");
  returnValue = myMethodInfo.Invoke(myObject, null);

  myObject = null;
}
```

Here is my question; When i click the button for the first time, Everything is OK. But when i click it again i get the following error;

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\temp.txt' because it is being used by another process.

The object returned from activator.createinstance doesnot seem to be nulled after first call. Although i assign it to a null value by `myObject = null` i still get the same error. Any ideas?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `GB` opens a `ReadWrite` stream to the file, but then never closes it. The subsequent invocation of `GB` attempts to open the same file, but this obviously fails.

What you need to do is implement `IDisposable` on `GB`, which disposes of the `StreamReader`, e.g.:

```
public class GB : IDisposable
{
    private StreamReader sr;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public GB()
    {
        sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:\\temp.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
    }
    public int MultiCall()
    {
        if (sr.ReadLine() == "test1")
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    ~GB()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool isManaged)
    {
        if(_isDisposed)
            return;

        if(isManaged)
        {
            // Ensure we close the file stream
            sr.Dispose();
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Then dispose of your `GB` instance once you are done with it.

```
// Dispose of the GB instance (which closes the file stream)
var asDisposable = (IDisposable)myObject;
asDisposable.Dispose();
```

[`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exists for exactly this reason, to ensure unmanaged resources are successfully released.

Comment: I thought by making the assignment `myObject = null`, **sr** would be  closed, which is appearently not as i thought. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By making `myObject = null`, you are merely allowing the instance of `GB` to be garbage collected, this may happen immediately, or it may not, just because `GB` becomes garbage collected, the file stream may not. Determinate resource release is the purpose of `IDisposable`, and your welcome, be sure to mark as answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Store the value returned by the file then check it value in the `MultiCall` method. This way you file gets closed and disposed for you.

```
public class GB
{
    private string str;
    public GB()
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:\\temp.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
        {
          str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
    public int MultiCall()
    {
        if (str == "test1")
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```